# Can I use -ing verbs within a sentence that's in the past tense?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, continuous-aspect, past-vs-present

Is this sentence grammatically correct? The dashes are em dashes. This is the last sentence of a paragraph that is in the past tense:

> But I continued to work—building, learning, and simply loving what I did—and nothing has been more rewarding.

And if not, can someone explain why and provide the correct way to structure it?

Comment: Yes, you can use -ing verbs in a past tense. Ex: "I was loving it". Your sentence seems correct to me. I don't know the rules of em dashes very well, so I'll leave it to someone else to answer more completely.

Comment: @iMerchant Except that *I was loving it*, strictly speaking, is not the past tense but the imperfect. However I will agree that what the OP has written is perfectly correct. *I carried on walking; I enjoyed running the business* etc are examples of the use of the present participle with the past tense.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. The interpolation _building, learning, and simply loving what I did_ is a supplement comprising a coordination of three subordinate non-finite clauses. Non-finite clause are tenseless, so there's no conflict with the past tense of the matrix clause. Btw, _I was loving it_ is a past tense, progressive aspect clause.

Answer (score 2):

We consider *-ing* verbs to be “non-finite” verb forms. That means that they are not inflected for person or number or tense.

To carry tense, you need a finite verb form, like your *continued* which is the past tense of *continue*, and like your *has* which is the present tense (and third person singular) of *have*.

Those other verbs like *loving*, though, they have no tense. Use them at will with either tense.

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean I need to change that "has been" because it doesn't match the tense of "continued"?

Comment: @sparkki No, you do not have to change it. It’s fine as is. These are two completely independent clauses — so independent thoughts — each with its own subject and verb.  Each has something of its own to say, and these need to use both tenses to do that with.